# Cant create graph with libchart in php

Tags: php, graph, ibm-cloud

I tried to create graph with `libchart` from array of points but PHP script cant pass this line :

```
$chart->render("parlament.png");
```

No errors , but also no graphs rendered.

Any ideas where can be a problem ? Here is code of this script :
[script](http://pastebin.com/F4wYxG00)

Thanks for every help :)

Comment: With the details provided it is difficult to understand which could be the issue. Has your application a Bluemix root to check it directly by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Libchart generates `parlament.png` file on site directory. You can echo generated file on your site.